# Return the start end index of the words present in a list in oyhton

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

Suppose I have a list of words and I want to search every word in a sentence present in a list and return the start and end index of it for example:

```
keyword_list = ['motorcycle', 'bike', 'cycle', 'dirtbike']
all_text = 'some rather long bike string'
```

output should be like this:

```
{bike: '17','20'}
```

Comment: `{bike: '17','20'}` this is not valid syntax in python

Comment: have you tried to solve it on your own?

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Comment: How should multiple occurrences of a keyword in all_text be handled? First match / all matches?

Comment: If `all_text = 'some rather long motorcycle string'`, should the output be `{motorcycle: (17,26), cycle: (22,26)}`, or are you only counting completely separate words?  And if you have `all_text = 'cycle cycle'` should the output be `{cycle: (0,4)}` or  `{cycle: (7,11)}` (I don't think it can be both if you use a dictionary).  This problem has edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you wish for:

```
keyword_list = ['motorcycle', 'bike', 'cycle', 'dirtbike']
all_text = 'some rather long bike string'
index_dict = {}
for item in keyword_list:
    if item in all_text:
        start_index = all_text.index(item)
        index_dict[item] = [start_index, start_index + len(item) -1]

print(index_dict)
```

Output is:

```
{'bike': [17, 20]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
result = {keyword: (all_text.index(keyword), all_text.index(keyword)+len(keyword)) for keyword in keyword_list if keyword in all_text}
```

This will create a mapping of all keywords that appear in all_text. `index(substr)` will return the index of the starting character, so `index(substr)+len(substr)` will return the end.

Comment: you're calling `all_text.index(keyword)` 2 times.

Comment: @VishalSingh Yes, if you called it once it would be more efficient, but no longer a oneliner

Comment: you need ```len(substr) - 1``` actually